# TypeScript: Exit command?

Tags: javascript, typescript

In a TypeScript file, is there a command to skip the execution of the rest of the file? In other words, can I jump to the end of the current file?

Currently I have something like this:

```
const isOkay = SomeCheckFunction();
if(isOkay)
{ 
    // do all the things we need to do if everything is okay
    // ...
}
```

But I'd like to invert the if statement to reduce nesting to something like: `if(!isOkay) { exit; }`

**EDIT:**
My file is executed in a browser and loaded as module by RequireJs.
Considering the answers I see that TS/JS does not provide this `exit` command I was looking for.

Comment: *if* it is in a function: `return;`

Comment: … and _if_  it is not in a function, wrap it with an IIFE: Immediately Invoked Function Expression. Then you can `return` any time.

Comment: I am trying to reduce nesting. That is, I do not want curly braces all around my code. So by wrapping my code in a function I wouldn't gain anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pretty "invasive" trick would be to `throw` an error. That will stop the execution but also "pollute" the dev console:

```js
const isOkay = SomeCheckFunction();
if(!isOkay) { 
    throw new Error('not okay');
}

// do all the things we need to do if everything is okay
// ...
```

We don't know your specific needs but in some cases, it could be acceptable.

Comment: Nice idea! So, I guess there *is* a way. But you are right. It *is* invasive. Not quite what I expected but definitely a way to achieve what I was looking for! So I accept this answer as it comes closest to the "exit" command I was looking for. I love SO, there are always people who think outside of my box! :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are asking of a general way for stopping the execution of a javascript file, I need to ask: who is running the file? A browser? In this case, I am afraid that there is no really useful way to do it. Node? In this case, you can try process.exit()

But I would recommend to wrap your file in a function, and return the funtion if necessary. Then call this function at the end of the file. This way the file execution is not stopped, but you can reach the same effect.

Note: it seems that your question is not related to typescript, it is a javascript question...

Answer (score 1):

The way to do that is to write your if statements as guard clauses.

Here is a good article about it:
[Writing Cleaner JavaScript with Guard Clauses](https://pjmcdermott92.medium.com/writing-cleaner-javascript-with-guard-clauses-fe4bb8788425)

So for example, instead of writing the code like this:

```js
function checkForPlayerStrike(strike) {
  if (playerStrikes.includes(strike)) {
    error = true
    error.message = 'You already hit this location.'
  }
}
```

You can write it like this:

```js
function checkForPlayerStrike(strike) {
  if (!playerStrikes.includes(strike)) return
  error = true
  error.message = 'You already hit this location.'
}
```

In your example it would look like this:

```js
function doThings() {
  const isOkay = SomeCheckFunction();
  if (!notOkey) return;
  doMoreThings();
}
```

Or a more useful example:

```
const MAX_AGE = 100;
const MIN_AGE = 1;

function hasValidAge(user: User): boolean {
  if (typeof user.age === 'number') return false;
  if (user.age < MIN_AGE) return false;
  if (user.age > MAX_AGE) return false;
  return true;
}
```